# How I manage TProgressBar in Delphi with process completed on TImage?

Tags: delphi

I have one progressbar and an image on my form. Now I am doing some processing on each scanline on image. I wanted to show progress of my process using progressbar. I set the following properties of progressbar :

```
Max = 20
Min = 0
Position = 0
Step = 1
Smooth = False
```

Now my code on buttonclick event is as under :

```
   stat := imgmain.Picture.Bitmap.Height div pbImage.Max;
   Curstatus := 0;
   for cnt := 0 to img.Picture.Bitmap.Height - 1 do begin
      for cnt1 := 0 to img.Picture.Bitmap.Width - 1 do begin
        //Some processing
      end;
      if cnt > (Curstatus + stat) then begin
         pgimg.StepIt;
         Curstatus := cnt + stat;
      end;    
   end;
```

My problem is when I run this code, the if block is executed exactly 20 times but it shows more than 20 steps on my progress bar. Also the last step is shown incomplete. Note that `smooth` property is set to false.

Comment: That's by design, the progress bar shows percentage of work complete, the "Max" and "Min" properties are there to help you specify how much work was completed. Think about it: How many blocks should the progress bar display if it's showing progress of copying a 1Mb file? 1 million blocks?

Comment: @Cosmin so you want to say that we should not change Max and Min value and accordingly calculate percentage of progress.??Is it so?

Comment: no, I'm saying don't expect to see (Max - Min + 1) blocks.

Comment: @Cosmin So, that is by design.. i.e., I was misunderstanding that there should be Max number of blocks if Min is 0. right? Please write this content as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Min, Max and Position** are used so the Progressbar can automatically how much work has been completed. Example:

```
Min := 100;
Max := 150;
Position := 125;
=> 50% work complete, the progress bar will be half-filled with green blocks.
```

**Step** is used so the progress bar knows how much to add to "Position" when you call **StepIt**. For example, if you'd do a progress bar for a file-copy operation, you might use something like this:

```
Min := 0;
Max := 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2Mb
Step := 4 * 1024; // 4Kb
Position := 0;

// in a loop, copy 4Kb blocks, and then do:
ProgressBar.StepIt; // this is equivalent to Position := Position + Step;
```

**Min and Max** have nothing to do with the number of blocks you see on screen, that's entirely implementation-specific. For example Windows versions before XP didn't show blocks, they showed a simple filled bar. The size of the blocks might even be theme-dependent! Windows will show sufficient blocks to express the percentage of complete work. Min, Max and Position are used to calculate that percentage.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
Max = 20 
Min = 0
```

You actually have 21 steps in your progress bar, with 0 being the first and 20 being the last.  Set Max to 19, and it should work.

Comment: I change this values and now `if block` is executed 19 times. But the problem is same, It will not make any difference because the value of `stat` is calculated using max value of progressbar.

Comment: @DwrCymru My code is working fine, It fills whole progressbar when process is completed, the problem with my code, your suggested code and even answered by DwrCymru is that it is not showing the number of blocks as specified by `Max` property. i.e., max = 19 but it is showing 24 blocks , max = 768 but showing 27 blocks

Answer (score 1):

Set the Max value to the height of your image and increase position after processing (or before) each scan line.

The only progress bar I know of that will behave the way you want is the "TJvXPProgressBar" (part of JEDI VCL [here](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org)) which will increase the number of blocks dsiplayed when Position is increased so with Max := 20, Min := 1 and Position := 5 there will be 5 blocks displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip:

If you change position value prior to do the job inside the loop, you will get a better visual effect, more if after last loop there is not much work left after the loop till progress is hide.

In other words:

```
TheProgressBar.Min:=0;
TheProgressBar.Max:=20;
TheProgressBar.Position:=0;
for i:=1 to 20
do begin
        // Do some job that take some time
        TheProgressBar.Position:=TheProgressBar.Position+1;
   end;
TheProgressBar.Visible:=False; // Or window is closed, etc
```

That will never show progressbar to rich the end, it will rich the end, but as soon as shown, the progressbar is hidden or window closed, etc, so user has no time to see it ends.

Just do the increment before the job, progressbar will show not how much has been done yet, but will show in what step it is working, so last step will be shown for as long as last step tooks, so user will se that progressbar be filled for a while.

And allways remember a progressbar has Max-Min+1 possible positions... so if Min is zero it will have one more than max value: first possition will be 0, second will be 1, etc, last one will be max.

If you want from 1 to 20, set min to 1, not to zero.

Theese are jsut tips, in case someone do not think on them.